# If represented by lawyer at divorce trial can I myself examine expert witness?

Tags: civil-procedure

The witness for the opposing party performed the valuation of business.  I happen to be in the same profession (I have not introduced my own valuation because of the potential conflict of interest) and feel qualified to ask the "technical" questions re. the expert's methodology, assumption etc.  I could spend time educating my attorney as to what questions to ask but it would have taken time (which is of the essence) and i believe I am still more competent to ask the immediate follow-up questions depending on the answers given.
Thanks for advice
origami

Comment: You'll have to state the jurisdiction in order to get an answer.  However, surely your lawyer will be more qualified to answer this than anyone here - and your lawyer can also advise you as to whether it's actually a good idea.

Comment: @NateEldredge and whether their lawyer would be willing to represent a client that wants to bypass them in a setting where they have a reputation to uphold.

Answer (score 1):

At least in the United States, when you are represented by a lawyer in a court case you may not examine witnesses yourself, even if you are more qualified to do so. This is a rule that judges will usually enforce strictly, even if no one objects to it.

Comment: You could ask to be recognized as co-counsel, couldn't you?  Ted Bundy was infamously co-counsel in his (first) murder trial, alongside public defenders, and he questioned witnesses.  He had legal training, but was not Bar certified in Florida (or anywhere else).  That was a good while ago, but presumably this is still possible?

Comment: @zibadawatimmy Yes. That happened to me when I represented myself in a criminal case one time --- the judge forced me to take a Pub Def to act as co-counsel. The same happened with the person who shot up the batman premiere a few years ago if memory serves. Idk with respect to civil cases. It would likely be governed by local rules or the judge's discretion.

Comment: @DavidReed FWIW, the criminal case was in Arapahoe County, Colorado. I forget if the civil case was there or in the U.S. District Court for the District of Colorado.